# Prevent parent event from triggering child events

Tags: javascript, events

So there are plenty of questions asking how to keep child events from triggering parent events, but I can't seem to find any for the opposite.

I toggle a parent event on and off like so:

```
var body_event = function(e){
    console.log('test');
};

$('#btn').toggle(
    function(e){
        $('body').bind('click', body_event);
    }, 
    function(){
        $('body').unbind('click', body_event);
    }
);
```

Currently if I run this on a page like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="btn">click to activate</div>
    <div id="example" onclick="alert('do not show this when event is bound')">
        try the body event by clicking here
    </div>
</body>
```

the toggle works fine, but when I click on "try the body event by clicking here" the alert will still show up.  I want to be able to ignore all child events when the body event is bound without individually referencing the child events.

In other words I'm looking for a better solution than doing something like this on toggle:

```
$('#example").attr('onclick', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is close, but not quite there. It doesn't check whether the specific function is bound, just whether there are any events bound to the jQuery object.

There must be a way to query the events to find if one is bound to click, and then subsequently what function it points too. Hopefully this gets you started though.

http://jsfiddle.net/PhjB8/

```
var body_event = function(e) {
    alert('test');
};

$('#btn').toggle(

function(e) {
    $('body').addClass('active').bind('click', body_event);
}, function() {
    $('body').removeClass('active').unbind('click', body_event);
});

$('#example').click(function() {
    //debugger;
    if ($('body').data('events') == undefined) {
        alert('do not show this when event is bound');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

event.stopPropagation() can solve this problem, inside body_event?

Comment: You have to reverse your thinking. If the parent has an event, then don't fire for the child. StopPropagation is only useful for the opposite scenario.

Comment: yeah, it is important to keep in mind that the child event is triggered before the parent event.